# Frozen "Still Working..." message when traversing rules in quality profile AND nameless rulesets in some rules

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I have a new instance of SQ 5.3.
I imported couple of Java quality profiles from another SQ 5.3 instance (migrated from SQ 5.1.2).

Then, when I open any Java quality profile I can see all rules belonging to it.
But when I click at a rule to see its definition then I see the message "Still Working..." which doesn't disappear at all, even after a long time!

What's more interesting: when I click at the 'scroll' button to get to the definition of the next rule then, for some rules, the definition appears while the message "Still Working..." is still being shown.

One more thing: in case of a rule which definition is show I see that the rule belongs to e.g. 2 rulesets: 'Sonar way' and to a ruleset *without* name! When I then try to remove the rule from the nameless ruleset I get the error message "Quality profile not found: java-sonar-way-28885"! Even if there is no ruleset with 28885 in the existing rulesets on SonarQube.

Update: I observe the problem with nameless rulesets in rules for all other languages, as well, e.g. Web or XML, even if I haven't changed there anything!

What caused the described errors? How can they be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

After:

1. Stopping SQ,
2. Deleting the folder '/data/es' (with Elastic Search data),
3. Starting SQ

everything worked fine again!

Nevertheless, the question stays: what caused the problem? Restoring quality profiles from files?